# Why is Python/Pandas "losing" thousands of rows of data despite apparently knowing they are there?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, missing-data

I am trying to work with a (British) police data set via an API regarding stop and search incidents.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook. I have imported the data via an API and then output a local copy to a CSV for reference purposes (this contains the full 6249 rows). I know that the dataset is 6249 rows in length too (see image), but when I enter the name of the dataset into a cell and run it to check it, it shows the first and last 5 rows as normal, but the tail end is telling me the dataset runs to only 541 rows?

[image]

I tried to output all of the values in one of the columns to a list to see if it would enter all 6250 to the list, but when I checked it has only put 541 in there....It's almost like Pandas knows these thousands of "missing" rows are there but is "ignoring" them for some reason?

I have dropped certain columns from the dataframe, but no rows and when I run the output to CSV function, the "Missing" rows are all present in the CSV file.

I tried using the display max rows function but it didn't work, it still only displays 541 rows:

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

I've tried running the .shape function and that is telling me that there are 6249 rows as well:

[image]

I've been working for hours on this but can't seem to find anything like this that has happened to others. It basically means that I cannot continue with my project because Pandas is refusing to recognise most of my data.

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated!

Many thanks,

T

Comment: Try: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`. The indices may not be in order or there are repeat indices perhaps.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a link to the original data.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for responding, the original link I imported the data from is: https://data.police.uk/api/stops-force?force=cleveland&date={date}

Comment: I had a quick look at the data set and it seems each month needs to be retrieved individually. 6249 _stop and searches_ in a month is much more than the few records I looked at.  Are you aggregating the retrieved data in some way?  For example, are the month's worth of data combined into years worth of data ... or multiple police forces are combined for each month?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. @JoynulIslam will be right. You will have concatenated 12 separate dfs, something like `df = pd.concat([df1, ..., df12])` for each of the months of `2021` (`6249 rows`). This keeps the original index values, thus creating duplicates. E.g. try `len(cleveland_police.loc[0,:])`, it will output: `12` (i.e. the first row of each individual `df`). Either use `reset_index` afterwards, or better, use: `df = pd.concat([df1, ..., df12], ignore_index=True)`. If not correct, please update your post with your *code*. In general, *always* post your actual code in your Q.